# jQuery count current div position from many other

Tags: jquery

**1st part** << SOLVED using $(this).index();

Let's say I have the below div structure, where the parent div doesn't have id or class:

```
<div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get an alert using jQuery with the current div position on mouse hover? Example: I'd like to receive "THIS IS DIV NUMBER 3" when hovering my mouse on the 3rd .myClass div.

**2nd part**
And what if I got the following structure, where $(this).index() is always returning zero no matter which one I'm hovering?

```
<div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you can see a TSUNAMI of answers....;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `index()` method on `mouseenter()`:

```js
$('div.myClass').mouseenter(function() {
  var idx = $(this).index() + 1;
  $('#output').text('THIS IS DIV NUMBER ' + idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">div1</div>
  <div class="myClass">div2</div>
  <div class="myClass">div3</div>
  <div class="myClass">div4</div>
  <div class="myClass">div5</div>
  <div class="myClass">div6</div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

For your second example you would need to provide a selector to `index()` as the elements are not all siblings:

```js
$('div.myClass').mouseenter(function() {
  var idx = $(this).index('.myClass') + 1;
  $('#output').text('THIS IS DIV NUMBER ' + idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">div1</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">div2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">div3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">div4</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">div5</div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked for the first scenario. I've added a 2nd scenario where the index() is always the same. Can you give a hand?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.myClass').mouseenter(function() {

  alert("This is din number " + ($(this).index()+1) )

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">1</div>
  <div class="myClass">2</div>
  <div class="myClass">3</div>
  <div class="myClass">4</div>
  <div class="myClass">5</div>
  <div class="myClass">6</div>
</div>
```

Use `.index()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked for the first scenario. I've added a 2nd scenario where the index() is always the same. Can you give a hand?

Comment: sure give more details on second scenario

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index()` function:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.myClass', function() {
  alert($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

```css
.myClass { 
  padding:15px;
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="myClass">1</div>
  <div class="myClass">2</div>
  <div class="myClass">3</div>
  <div class="myClass">4</div>
  <div class="myClass">5</div>
  <div class="myClass">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add 1 to index, as its zero based

Comment: OP wants to get 3 when hover on div 3 index starts with 0

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked for the first scenario. I've added a 2nd scenario where the index() is always the same. Can you give a hand?